# abrir puerto con windows server 2012 r2 digitalocean

Tags: mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Instale en el vps de digitalocean windows server 2012 r2, pero no me permite abrir puertos. Ya lo hice con la configuracion del firewall y he desactivado el firewall pero no me abre ningun puerto

Comment: Como estas seguro de que los puertos no están abiertos? Por las etiquetas puedo suponer que estas trabajando con MySQL.... MySQL por defecto no permite conexiones externas pero no tiene nada que ver con Windows es una configuración de MySQL Server... Por favor danos un poco más de información para poder ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Es MySQL o SQL-Server?